# Filtro en ng-repeat no funciona como se espera

Tags: angularjs

Tengo el siguiente JSON:

```
[{
    "IdModulo": 1,
    "IdPadre": 0,
    "Nombre": "Home",
    "Ruta": "menu.home",
}, {
    "IdModulo": 2,
    "IdPadre": 0,
    "Nombre": "Administrador",
    "Ruta": "menu.administrador"
}, {
    "IdModulo": 3,
    "IdPadre": 0,
    "Nombre": "Informes",
    "Ruta": "menu.informes"
}, {
    "IdModulo": 4,
    "IdPadre": 2,
    "Nombre": "Carga archivo",
    "Ruta": "menu.administrador"
}, {
    "IdModulo": 5,
    "IdPadre": 2,
    "Nombre": "Verificación",
    "Ruta": "menu.verificacion"
}, {
    "IdModulo": 6,
    "IdPadre": 2,
    "Nombre": "Procesados",
    "Ruta": "menu.procesados"
}, {
    "IdModulo": 7,
    "IdPadre": 2,
    "Nombre": "Hyperion",
    "Ruta": "menu.hyperion"
}, {
    "IdModulo": 10,
    "IdPadre": 2,
    "Nombre": "Clientes",
    "Ruta": "menu.clientes"
}, {
    "IdModulo": 8,
    "IdPadre": 3,
    "Nombre": "Reclasificaciones",
    "Ruta": "menu.reclasificacion"
}, {
    "IdModulo": 9,
    "IdPadre": 3,
    "Nombre": "Resumen",
    "Ruta": "menu.resumen"
}]
```

El cual deseo filtrar para que solo me genere aquellos elementos cuyo `IdPadre = 0`.

Uso este código para generar los elementos con la condición `IdPadre = 0`:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     <li ng-repeat="menues in menu | filter: IdPadre = 0" ng-class="getClass('/{{menues.Nombre.toLowerCase()}}')" class="" ng-click="cargarItemsDelMenu(menues.IdModulo)">
        <a ui-sref="{{menues.Ruta}}">
           <span>{{menues.Nombre.toUpperCase()}}</span>
        </a>
     </li>
 </ul>
```

Pero *(además de los elementos que cumplen la condición)* me trae el elemento "Clientes" - éste no debería traerlo, porque su `IdPadre = 2`.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal y cómo logro filtrar correctamente los valores según el filtro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buen día mauro, tienes el siguiente error dentro de `json` que tienes,

```
{
    "IdModulo": 1,
    "IdPadre": 0,
    "Nombre": "Home",
    "Ruta": "menu.home",
}
```

tienes una "," después del elemento `Ruta:"menu.home"` por lo cual tienes que eliminar esa `COMA`, ahora lo que tienes que hacer es que dentro de la linea del `ng-repeat` es hacer el `filter` de esta manera `ng-repeat="data in datos | filter: { IdPadre: 0 }"`, espero que te funcione si algo me comentas.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Si funcionó. Soy nuevo en Angular :). Respecto a la coma sobrante, en realidad hay mas parejas de llaves y valores, pero los omití del ejemplo. Saludos.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave dale estamos para ayudar !!